# doing multiple mazes from a text file in java

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I am new to stackoverflow and Java. I have been working on this project for quite a while(about a week), I need to create a maze solver that runs from [0,0] to [9,9] of each text field(idk if I'm using the correct term). Each maze is seperated by one empty line. I have the program to display the maze correctly but now the problem arises that I can't get it to solve each maze, only the last maze in the text file, even if I change the order of the mazes, it just solves the last one. The program runs the last maze in the set of mazes but I can't get it to start from the first one and do each one consecutively, here is the code I worked on:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Maze
{
private static char[][] maze;

private static ArrayList<String> mazegenerator;

public static void initializeMaze(String fileName)
{
        try
          {
    mazegenerator = new ArrayList<>();
    int numcols = 0;
            int r = 0;

        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String nextLine = file.nextLine(); // sets the String nextLine a value
                                mazegenerator.add(nextLine); // inserts the string into the array
            if (nextLine.length() > numcols)
                numcols = nextLine.length(); //sets numcols to the length of the Line
                            if(nextLine.length() == 0)
                                clearthismaze(); // clears the input from array
        } // loop to collect the cols and set the row size

    int numrows = mazegenerator.size();
    maze = new char[numrows][numcols];
    for (int i ; r < numrows; r ++)
    {
        String row = mazegenerator.get(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < numcols; c++)
        {
            if(row.length() >= c)
                maze[r][c]= row.charAt(c);
        }
    }
            if(r == 10 && numrows == 10 && numcols == 10)
                System.out.println();
                printMaze();
                solveMaze(0,0);
                System.out.println();
                printMaze();
                numrows = 0;
                numcols = 0;
          }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println(fileName + " has an issue");} 


} // this method generates the maze and sets it up which is later printed

public static void printMaze()
{
    for (char[] row: maze)
    {
        for (char c: row)
            System.out.print(c);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

} //method to print maze accordingly

public static void main (String[] args)
{       
            System.out.println("This program prints the original maze before solving and then prints the maze solution, \n"
                    + "solving from the upper left to the lower right. X's represent routes taken, 2's represent the true path, \n"
                    + "if no 2's are present then that means the maze is unsolvable \n");
    initializeMaze("multiplemazes.txt");
} // main method , driver method

public static boolean solveMaze(int r, int c)
{
    boolean finished = false;
    if(PossibleToMove(r,c)){
         maze[r][c] = 'X'; // coordinate has been visited mark it so you don't return to it                                                  
         if(c == maze[0].length - 1 && r == maze.length-1)// base case: did I reach destination?
         finished = true;  // maze is solved   
    else{              

        if(!finished)
            finished = solveMaze(r,c-2); // look left
        if(!finished)
            finished = solveMaze(r-1,c); // look up
        if(!finished)
            finished = solveMaze(r,c+2); // look right
        if(!finished)
            finished = solveMaze(r+1,c); // look down
    }
        if(finished) // part of the true path
            maze[r][c] = '2';
        if(!finished){
            System.out.println(">>>" + " Backtracking from " + "( " + r + ", " + c/2 + ")");               
        }
    }
    // if I know that I reached a dead end
    // this can't be part of the solution
    return finished;         
} //method solveMaze

private static boolean PossibleToMove(int r, int c){
boolean canmove  = false;

if(r >=0 && r < maze.length && c >=0 && c < maze[0].length)
   if(maze[r][c] == '0')
       canmove = true;

return canmove;
}  // method PossibleToMove
public static void clearthismaze(){
mazegenerator.clear();
}
} // class Maze
```

Here is the text file sample of 4 mazes:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0

0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

any amount of help would be useful, and yes it is a homework assignment, I think I'm just stuck on a looping issue, or something is wrong with my clearthismaze() method. My intentions are the print out the array, solve the array, clear the array, skip the empty line and then move onto the next array. If someone can just pinpoint the issue I'd be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you need to go 2 steps to get the left/right maze?

Comment: I was skipping the empty space between the integers since I didn't know how to parse the space between the two integers a char array. it was a quick fix method for the meantime. Before it was counting the space as it traversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're clearing the `mazegenerator` if you get an empty line. So if you start to solve the maze only the last one is available.

You can change the type to `List<List<String>> mazegenerator`. So `mazegenerator.get(0)` holds the first maze, `mazegenerator.get(0).get(0)` holds the first line of the first maze.
You also need to change your file reading loop:

```
List<String> singleMaze = new ArrayList<>();
while(file.hasNextLine()) {
    // ...
    if(nextLine.length() == 0) {
        mazegenerator.add(singleMaze);
        singleMaze = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: I can't get the final maze to display, I can cycle through the first 3 by changing the number in mazegenerator.get().get(r) for example, but how do I get mazegenerator.get(3)  (the final one)? even if I have a hundred mazes, I can only get 99 but not the 100th one, is there something wrong with my reading?

Comment: put your solving code into a loop `for (List<String> singleMaze : mazegenerator)`. This will iterate through all mazes (doesn't matter if 3, 4 or 100)